# Django Migration-SQL Server

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am just learning Django, I have created a model inside an app Book

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    read = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now I want to generate it's correspondence SQL sentence with the help of

```
python manage.py sql books
```

But it's showing me error

> CommandError: App 'Books' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.

I have used `makemigrartion` and `migrate` command it's showing no migration is remaining.

Can anyone have any idea regarding to this error?

Comment: What sql are you wanting? The select statements or the create statements? Also curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, interesting. Right now, there are two ways of turning models into SQL. The old syncdb method, which will ultimately be removed, and the new migrations method. The old `sql*` commands were based on the first method, and won't generally work the same way with the migrations approach. So I think this is a technical limitation (though perhaps it's philosophical as well).

Probably the best way to accomplish this is to first [squash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) your migrations (in most cases this should produce a single migrations file) and then generate the SQL for that new migration with the `sqlmigrate` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still a bit of backwards compatibility with django 1.6 and below you can still use the sql commands from django-admin. However, you have to delete the migrations folder first.

To get the create statements you need to remove the migrations folder

```
rm -rf books/migrations
```

Then you can run the sql statement

```
./manage.py sql books
```

Should give you something like this:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "books_book" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "title" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "author" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "read" varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

However if what you are after is the select statements. Add back your migrations folder:

```
mkdir books/migrations/
```

Then do your create migrations and migrate commands.

From there open up the shell:

```
./manage.py shell
```

In the shell you can create a queryset and print the query:

```
from books.models import Book
print Book.objects.all().query
```

With that you should get an output like this:

```
SELECT "book_book"."id", "book_book"."title", "book_book"."author", "book_book"."read" FROM "book_book"
```

Those are a couple of ways to get sql back, depending on what you are trying to generate. The great thing about the queryset in the shell is you can make that as complex as possible and do a print of the `.query` and it gives it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the app, there will be a directory for migrations where the django will store your model changes as migrations files.

To see the query you have to use the command `python manage.py sqlmigrate {your_app_name;{eg :polls}} {migrations_file_name:{eg:0001_init.py}}`

command:

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001
```

Hope this will help